# Materialized view in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is Materialized view in Oracle? What is the use of it? I searched this topic on the net but i cannot able to get an clear idea of it. So can you please explain this topic with an clear example. So that it will be more useful for me to understand the topic clearly.

Comment: Start by looking at the manual: [Basic Materialized Views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/basicmv.htm#i1007299) and [Advanced Materialized Views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/advmv.htm#i1007694).

Answer (score 7):

A Materialized view is an RDMS provided mechanism to trade additional storage consumption for better query performance.

For example suppose that you have a really big query with 10 table joins that takes a long time to return data. If you convert the query into a materialized view the **results** of this query will be materialized into a special db table on disk automatically, whats even better is that as rows are added/updated/deleted they are automatically reflected in the materialized view.

The tradeoff of this handy tool is slower inserts and updates on underlying tables though. Materialized views is one of the few redeeming qualities of Oracle IMHO.

Here is an example of a two table join `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_Test
  NOLOGGING
  CACHE
  BUILD IMMEDIATE 
  REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT 
  AS
    SELECT V.*, P.*, V.ROWID as V_ROWID, P.ROWID as P_ROWID, (2+1) as Calc1, 'Constant1' as Const1
    FROM TPM_PROJECTVERSION V
         INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECT P ON P.PROJECTID = V.PROJECTID
```

Now instead of running this same query everytime you can just run this simpler query against your new view which will run faster. The really cool thing is that you can also add derived and calculated columns too.

```
SELECT * FROM MV_Test WHERE ...
```

P.S.

`MATERIALIZED VIEWS` are not a panacea, use them in cases where you have a really slow query with lots of joins that is frequently used and where the reads far outweigh the writes.

Comment: sir can you please explain it with an simple example.

Comment: sir the same can be done in a VIEW itself. Then what is the need for an MATERIALIZED VIEW.

Comment: A view will re-run the underlying query each time it's queried, a materialized view will not. Think of it like a query results `cache` that is automatically updated by the DB behind the scenes as the underlying table data is changed.

Comment: sir if i try to create a MATERIALIZED VIEW, it produce an error     (ORA-01031: insufficient privileges) at run time. How to solve it sir.

Comment: That is not in the scope of this question. The question you asked has been answered, please accept the answer and create another question relating to that issue.

Answer (score 1):

A (nearly) real-world example.

Suppose you were asked to develop an enterprise-wide real-time inventory report that will output total worth of inventory across all warehouses of the enterprise.

You would then need to create a query to

1. sum up all transaction stored in the inventory transaction table grouped by item and warehouse
2. join the sums with the table storing current price per unit of measure
3. sum up again per warehouse

In an enterprise, such a query would take hours to complete (even medium companies may have hundreds of thousands of different items) and its performance would deteriorate over time (imagine this query running over 5 years of data).

So, you would write the same (more or less) query as a materialized view. When created, oracle will populate a table (think of it as a hidden table) with the results of your query, and then, each time a transaction is commited to the inventory, will update the record that has to do with this specific item. If an item's price has changed, it will update its worth. In general, every change on the underlying tables will be reflected on your materialized view immediately. Then, your report will run at a very reasonable time.

On top of that, by using GROUPING BY and GROUPING you may get different levels of drilling on the same Materialized View.

Keep in mind, though, that this is an idealized example. In practice, ON COMMIT (i.e. updating the matierialized view the same time with your underlying tables) may cause problems when you create a materialized view over frequently update tables (and inventory transactions are usually that) and you may write, depending on the case, intermediate MVs to boost up performance. Refreshing such a view every 5 minutes is a viable alternative.

MVs are a very powerful feature, but you need to use them with care.

Answer (score 0):

> What is a Materialized View?
>
> A materialized view is a replica of a target master from a single
>   point in time. The master can be either a master table at a master
>   site or a master materialized view at a materialized view site.
>   Whereas in multimaster replication tables are continuously updated by
>   other master sites, materialized views are updated from one or more
>   masters through individual batch updates, known as a refreshes, from a
>   single master site or master materialized view site, as illustrated in
>   Figure 3-1. The arrows in Figure 3-1 represent database links.

--http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm

Example-- creates a materialized view for employees table. The refresh can be set to preference, so read documentation in link above.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW employee_mv
REFRESH FORCE
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT * FROM employees
```

A materialized view can also only contain a subset of data

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW employee_mv
REFRESH FORCE
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT name, ssn, address FROM employees
```

Comment: sir can you please explain it with an simple example.

Comment: sir the above code is not running, it produce an error (ORA-00905: missing keyword) while on running.